# Is there a general formula for the angles of reflection in a rectangular billiards table?

Tags: geometry, dynamical-systems

While writing a program, I encountered a problem in which I needed to calculate the angles of reflection of in a rectangular billiards table. Let's say that we look at the table from above, and that we have a reference angle of $0$ degrees facing north. How do we calculate the angles of reflection of the billiards balls reflecting from the upper, left, lower and right bounds of the table?

Comment: Angle of incidence equals angle of reflection.

Comment: Reflection angle depends on velocity vector of the ball and a normal of the bound. Do you want to have a single formula for all four cases, or are you asking about the general reflection formula?

Comment: for a standard rolling billard ball or for one with nontrivial rotation?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen for a standard rolling ball. To KarolisJuodele: I would like to be able to tell my program how the balls bounce off from the different bounds. The velocity doesn't matter, there is no friction. I don't really mind whether it's a general formuala or a formula for all different cases, as long as I am able to make the program work I'm happy :-) .

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of the program?

Comment: Ok never mind I figured it out 'already'. I will delete the question. Sorry if you had already started working on it / thinking about it.